# Enabling Constraint Silently Fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, foreign-key, constraint

Why would SQL Server silently fail to re-enable a foreign key constraint?

I recently attempted to re-enable a number of constraints using `ALTER TABLE`. Most enabled successfully; however, minority of the constrains are still reported as disabled by `sys.foreign_keys`.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] WITH CHECK NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_ConstraintName; 
-- Command(s) completed successfully.

SELECT is_disabled FROM sys.foreign_keys 
WHERE name = 'FK_Constraint' AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Table]');
-- returns "1", indicating that the constraint is still disabled
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `WITH CHECK CHECK` instead of `WITH CHECK NOCHECK` or is that a typo?

Comment: `CHECK CHECK` not `CHECK NOCHECK`, otherwise your key is not created correctly and will be untrusted and not used by the optimiser

Comment: @TomV & @MarkSinkinson, unfortunately it is `WITH CHECK NOCHECK`. The existing data isn't under my control or mine to change. The best I can do is ensure that future data complies with the constraint.

Comment: @BenGribaudo see my answer. You've got these the wrong way round :-) You'll want `WITH NOCHECK CHECK`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that you are not actually re-enabling your constraint (as defined by the `NOCHECK`).

The syntax for re-enabling a constraint is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename>
WITH { CHECK | NOCHECK }
CHECK CONSTRAINT <constraintname>;
```

The `WITH CHECK|NOCHECK` tells SQL Server whether or not you want to check the existing data in the table against the constraint. If you state `NOCHECK` here, then your constraint will be untrusted, defined by `is_not_trusted = 1` in `sys.foreign_keys`.

By stating `NOCHECK` as the second part, you're actually saying **disable the constraint**.

In your case, if you do not want to check the existing data, you'll need to `NOCHECK CHECK`.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] WITH NOCHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_ConstraintName;
```

[Further reading on trusting your constraints](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2007/03/can-you-trust-your-constraints/).

Comment: Thanks, @MarkSinkinson! I needed to swap the positions of my `CHECK` and `NOCHECK`.

Comment: I hate this syntax. How much check could a nocheck check if a nocheck could check check.